# How to auto reload or refresh a Web Page at a Specific given time?

Tags: php, time

I am working with a API. The problem is this API gives results once EVERY 60 Seconds. Its programmed to deliver results 06 Seconds past every minute.
So that would be 00:06 (MM:SS), 01:06, 02:06 so on....

I would like to have 2 seconds margin so I want to Refresh my page at 08 Seconds paste every minute.

I am not a programmer but learning, the solution below works perfectly for my use, but I guess its not the correct way to do?

Is it any other shorter way to achieve the results from this code:

```
<?php

$nowis = date('s');

if ( $nowis == "00" ) {$reload = "08" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "01" ) {$reload = "07" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "02" ) {$reload = "06" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "03" ) {$reload = "05" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "04" ) {$reload = "04" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "05" ) {$reload = "03" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "06" ) {$reload = "62" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "07" ) {$reload = "61" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "08" ) {$reload = "60" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "09" ) {$reload = "59" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "10" ) {$reload = "58" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "11" ) {$reload = "57" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "12" ) {$reload = "56" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "13" ) {$reload = "55" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "14" ) {$reload = "54" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "15" ) {$reload = "53" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "16" ) {$reload = "52" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "17" ) {$reload = "51" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "18" ) {$reload = "50" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "19" ) {$reload = "49" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "20" ) {$reload = "48" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "21" ) {$reload = "47" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "22" ) {$reload = "46" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "23" ) {$reload = "45" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "24" ) {$reload = "44" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "25" ) {$reload = "43" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "26" ) {$reload = "42" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "27" ) {$reload = "41" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "28" ) {$reload = "40" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "29" ) {$reload = "39" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "30" ) {$reload = "38" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "31" ) {$reload = "37" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "32" ) {$reload = "36" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "33" ) {$reload = "35" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "34" ) {$reload = "34" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "35" ) {$reload = "33" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "36" ) {$reload = "32" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "37" ) {$reload = "31" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "38" ) {$reload = "30" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "39" ) {$reload = "29" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "40" ) {$reload = "28" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "41" ) {$reload = "27" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "42" ) {$reload = "26" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "43" ) {$reload = "25" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "44" ) {$reload = "24" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "45" ) {$reload = "23" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "46" ) {$reload = "22" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "47" ) {$reload = "21" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "48" ) {$reload = "20" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "49" ) {$reload = "19" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "50" ) {$reload = "18" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "51" ) {$reload = "17" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "52" ) {$reload = "16" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "53" ) {$reload = "15" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "54" ) {$reload = "14" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "55" ) {$reload = "13" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "56" ) {$reload = "12" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "57" ) {$reload = "11" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "58" ) {$reload = "10" ;} 
if ( $nowis == "59" ) {$reload = "09" ;} 

echo $nowis;
echo " - ";
echo $reload;

?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $reload; ?>" >
```

I dont want to use any Java or other.. Please advice me a better way with PHP?

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest using JavaScript and even AJAX depending on how much you want to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Just some math instead of `if`.

```
<?php
$nowis = date('s');
$reload = (8 - $nowis + 60) % 60;
echo $nowis;
echo " - ";
echo $reload;
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $reload; ?>" >
```

This looks like what your big long `if` statement was doing.  And it appears to give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
$now = date('s');
$reload = (8 - $now) %  60;
header("refresh: $reload; url=page.php");
```

Comment: I also recomend you to check jQuery out.

Answer (score 0):

use Timers of javascript:

```
// refresh 60 seconds later, only once,
var timeoutId = setTimeout(new function(){location.reload() }, 60 * 1000);

// clear the setTimeout, so that it won't refresh if not yet,
clearTimeout(timeoutId);

// refresh every 20 seconds, repeatly,
var intervalId = setInterval(new function(){location.reload() }, 20 * 1000)

// clear the setInterval, so that it will stop refresh frequently,
window.clearInterval(intervalId)
```

Comment: he said no other language :D

Comment: @OzanKurt in that case, you can config the interval in .properties file, and load it via php, send to client-side via json, so that javascript can read it too, then javascript could control according to the params, and php has ability to modify the property. By the way, I think the asker can be more flexible, only use one way or one language don't really benifit.

Comment: I think you're right. But what if he/she doesnt know that much js?

Comment: @OzanKurt if he/she is doing web programming ... javascript is quite necessary, <javascript: the definitive guide 6th> would be helpful,^^

Comment: Yes, js makes things much easier.